# Posting with facebook api a message containing friend's names as links

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do a simple thing yet it seems none of the FB api options (Graph/others) seem to be able to solve it.

Say "Johny Brown" is my friend and I want to include his name in a wall post. What I can do is type @Johny Brown then facebook shows a nice dropdown from which I can select his name.

However the same behavior cannot be mimicked using Facebook API.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated. I tried "@" before name, using full url, using "Name" etc. None of them work.

Answer (score 2):

yup you're correct. in the new graph api facebook simply removed this feature (possibly due to too much spamming).

Comment: @kayson please provide documentation URL